# Categorizing Knockout js selection box

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Suppose I have the following knockoutjs binding

```
var optionsWithCategory = [
  "Category: Person", // Category option should be disabled, or non-selectable
  "Jason",
  "John",

  "Category: Department",
  "Human Resource",
  "Sales"
];

<div id="selectBox">
<select databind="options: optionsWithCategory"></select>
</div>
```

What are some of the approaches I can take to add `disable="disable"` to all `options` DOM element that has text value starts with `Category:`.  So that `Person` and `Department` would actually be non-selectable, but act as a separator in the select box.  Also, the `select` box is added dynamically to the `selectBox` div element.

One way I came up is:

```
$('#selectBox').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function (e) {
    if (e.target.text != undefined && e.target.text.indexOf(':') >= 0) {
        $(e.target).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

But it doesnt seem too elegant, is there any other ways?

Comment: You could to that, or you could create your own binding handler to do it too. But I'm confused on why you would want to have a single drop down list with 2 sets of data in it? Why not use 2 different html <select>'s?

Comment: @JohnPapa well, it is a bad example data, but there are uses for it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there are any clean ways to do this as its a bit of an uncommon use

But you could do similar code to what you have written, or you could create your own binding handler to do it too.  I'd suggest a binding handler since it will wrap up all the logic in one place.